# ViewPager disapear when fragment move

Tags: android, android-fragments

I already use

> getChildFragmentManager and CustomPager

but my view pager always disapear when i move the fragment.

This is my setupViewPager

```
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    MyPagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new PulsaFragment(), "Pulsa");
    adapter.addFragment(new TelkomFragment(), "Telkom");
    adapter.addFragment(new BPJSFragment(), "BPJS");
    adapter.addFragment(new ListrikFragment(), "Listrik");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

and myPagerAdapter

```
class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();
    private int mCurrentPosition = -1;

    @Override
    public void setPrimaryItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        super.setPrimaryItem(container, position, object);
        if (position != mCurrentPosition) {
            Fragment fragment = (Fragment) object;
            CustomPager pager = (CustomPager) container;
            if (fragment != null && fragment.getView() != null) {
                mCurrentPosition = position;
                pager.measureCurrentView(fragment.getView());
            }
        }
    }

    MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }

}
```

please help me :)
I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42836140/content-of-viewpager-disapear-after-changing-fragments)  but its not working..

Comment: `i move the fragment` what does this mean? how you move it?

Comment: above code is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```